# Blueprint CSS framework or any Grid system: fix for bordered divs

Tags: css, gridview, grid, blueprint-css

I've got some problems while trying to lay out my site. I'm using [Blueprint Framework](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) and it happens when I apply borders to my div. Since their width are controlled by `span-XX` (or `grid-xx` as I noticed in [960gs](http://960.gs)), the moment I apply borders to any `div` element I have it goes out of the grid as seen in these images [image: out] [Click to zoom](http://img37.imageshack.us/i/59550451.png/)
[image]
[Click to zoom](http://img687.imageshack.us/f/so2i.png/)

The only way I know to fix it is to change element's width, but then the framework's grid purpose finishes 'cause I won't have the `span-XX` classes anymore. Is there any other way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it right, you have a `span-24` or something similar and want to add a border to it, right? My preferred way of doing it is

```
<div class="span-24">
    <div class="box">here</div>
</div>
```

and add the border to the `box` class for above snippet.

Comment: Second this.  You can always change the width of the element in the framework, but this just leads to problems in the end sometimes when trying to maintain multiple versions with and without borders.  Nesting div's is technically a little nasty, but then again grid frameworks are built more for prototyping than production use. Teja has the general recommended solution.

Comment: Won't It have a line-break in this case for the first example?

Comment: I wiped out the `span-24` class from the inner div and did as you said but the bordered div appears with 1px height. The div inside it (which contains the input and the button) appears correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to nest divs, you can create a few additional classes for bordered columns. I'm using 1px borders, so I created classes like:

```
.with-border-first {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.with-border {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: -1px; 
  margin-right: 9px;
}

.with-border-last {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: -2px;
}
```

There should be one more if you want borders around divs spanning all columns (eg. 24 in blueprint).

I then use those classes together with the spans, for example:

```
<div class="span-8 with-border-first">
...
</div>

<div class="span-8 with-border">
...
</div>

<div class="span-8 last with-border-last">
...
</div>
```